# The role of Radha in various Vaishnava traditions

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, radha, nimbarkacharya, vallabhacharya

How do sampradayas other than Nimbarka or Gaudiya view the authenticity of the character of Radha?

Comment: Rejecting Rādhā is kinda foolish. Karapātrī Svāmi wrote the book 'Rādhā Sudhā' https://archive.org/details/radhasudha . But usually Advaitins aren't considered Vaiṣṇavas by many Vaiṣṇava sampradāyas. Rāmānandīs, Śrī Vaiṣṇavas, and Vārakarīs accept Rādhā. I am not sure on the position of Puṣṭimargis. And usually, most modern-day Dvaitins I have seen, tend to reject Rādhā.

Comment: Of course, there is a strain since pre-colonial times, which has began a nonsensical accusation of interpolation in all itihāsa-purāṇa śāstras. And many such people also call the mentions of Rādhā in śāstras, as being interpolations. These people lack śraddhā, and shouldn't be paid attention to, on this matter. By doubting the existence of Rādhā, they are indirectly also doubting the existence of Kṛṣṇa, for wherever there's Kṛṣṇa, there's Rādhā & vice-versa.

Comment: I didn't ask what faith is foolish. Everyone has their own beliefs and can believe whatever they want. My question was about Vaishnava traditions that do not recognize the role of Radha as authentic.